# A holomorphic line integral?

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f$ be a holomorphic function on a connected open set $U$ which contains the unit disc $D$, and suppose $|f(z)| \geq 1$ for $|z| = 1$.  For $w \in D$, the argument principle tells us that $$\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int\limits_{\partial D} \frac{f'}{f-w}$$ is $\geq 1$ if $w$ is in the image of $f_{|D}$, and $0$ otherwise.  My question is, what happens if we vary $w$, i.e. define $h: D \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ by $$h(w) = \frac{1}{2\pi i}\int\limits_{\partial D} \frac{f'}{f-w}$$ Is this $h$ continuous?  Holomorphic?  If $w$ is not in the image of $f$, then I'd like to say that $\frac{f'}{f - w} = \frac{d}{dz} \log(f(z) - w)$, but then I don't know if we can define the logarithm here without running into trouble.